# How do I convert a JSON string into and an array of unknown objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, string

I'm creating a simple flashcard generator and have a JSON String containing multiple arrays and objects that looks like this:

`data = [{"front":"What is your name?","back":"Billy"},{"front":"How old are you?","back":"40"}][{"front":"Is this a test?","back":"yes"}]`

When I `console.log(data.length)` i get 130.

I can enter more than one flashcard at a time, and can enter the flashcards at any given time. That's why there's the `][` are in the middle of it.

I'm trying to loop through said array and end up with something along the lines of:

`data = [{"front":"What is your name?","back":"Billy"},{"front":"How old are you?","back":"40"},{"front":"Is this a test?","back":"yes"}]`

Where `console.log(data.length) = 3`

And eventually `data[i].front = "What is your name?"`

Can someone please put me in the right direction? The data is being read from a txt file if that makes a difference.

Comment: That's not valid json.  You have an array tacked onto the outside of another array with no enclosing construct.

Comment: Your `data` is not a valid array.

Comment: `var data = JSON.parse(aValidJsonString);`

Comment: @Thomas `JSON.parse()` will barf with that input. @trincot, data is a string, apparently... based on `data.length`.

Comment: also, json does not have assignments like `data = `.  It looks like what you have there might be trying to be a javascript assignment using, mabey, an arary.  but as stated, its not a valid array.

Comment: As others have pointed out, your data is not valid JSON.  If it is meant to be an array of array of objects then the following outline would work: `[[{ ... },{ ...}],[{ .... }], ... ]`

Comment: show us the text file (or at least part of it if it is large) to see how the json should be formatted

Comment: Everything after "data =" is what I get when I console.log(data) from the txt file using fs.readFile. Since it's invalid JSON should i adjust the part of my code during the fs.appendFile part? The flashcards are put into an array, and the array is appended to the txt file. I feel like adjusting that would be easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if you are not controlling "json" creation, and can't get valid JSON, then just try to fix it.

```
const fixedData = data.replace('][', ',');
const parsedData = JSON.parse(fixedData);
console.log(parsedData.length); // 3
```

If you can control input, just construct valid JSON. Ask different question if don't know how.